# Strange variable error

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I've written the following code and made a variable for a second code piece
first:

```
$user_id=1;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_want_job WHERE user_id=$user_id");
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { 
$aa="$row2[1]"; 
}
echo $aa; // return: abc
```

second:

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_job WHERE job_nam ='$aa'"); 
while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_row($result2)) { 
$az="$row3[2]";}
echo $az;
```

now when i use $aa variable in secound code return this error!!!

```
-Undefined variable- az in
```

but when i change '$aa' whith "abc" i dont get error!!
thanks

Comment: While this won't fix your problem, please note the `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: Also, this question is about both `PHP` and `MySQL`. I've tagged both languages for you, but please remember to tag your questions with the relevant language tags in the future; `variables` exist in most languages, and not everyone is familiar with `PHP` variables.

Comment: In your first block of code, the while curly brace ends after each assignment (meaning you've only got the last assignment in $aa. Where does the curly brace end in your second block of code?

Comment: i fix the code... the curly brace accidently was erased

Comment: Add this:  print("SELECT * FROM tbl_job WHERE job_nam ='$aa'");  If your query is not proper, it could be a scope problem.  It that is the case, put the entire code, like it is now, it looks ok (or you have a problem in the $row3[2].  The result could be another format than what you expect?).

Comment: <?php
$user_id="0";
mysql_select_db("proj1");
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_want_job WHERE user_id=$user_id");
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2)) { 
$zz="$row2[0]";
$aa="$row2[1]"; 
$bb="$row2[2]";
$cc="$row2[3]";
$dd="$row2[4]";
$ee="$row2[5]"; 
$ff="$row2[6]"; 
$gg="$row2[7]";
}

echo $cc;
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_job WHERE job_nam = '$cc'"); 
while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_row($result3)) { 
$az="$row3[2]";
$bz="$row3[6]"; 
$cz="$row3[3]"; 
$dz="$row3[4]";
$ez="$row3[5]";
;
} 
echo "$az";
?>

Comment: abc
Notice: Undefined variable: az in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\index\panel-afer\pan-afrer-job - Copy.php on line 31

Comment: that is all cods and output

Answer (score 0):

The second result set does not return back a result, hence the error.

Comment: i fix that..this has been erased by mistake

Comment: The second result set does not return back a result,.. doesn't enter the while loop , which should cause the error. The first $aa seems to be not in scope when it reaches the second query.

Comment: when i change '$aa' whith "abc" i dont get error and i have result

Comment: can you use below code for debugging and paste the output.
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_job WHERE job_nam ='$aa'"); 
echo "SELECT * FROM tbl_job WHERE job_nam ='$aa'";
while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_row($result2)) { 
print_r($row3);
$az="$row3[2]";}
echo $az;

Comment: return this :SELECT * FROM tbl_job WHERE job_nam ='abc'
Notice: Undefined variable: az in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\index\panel-afer\pan-afrer-job - Copy.php on line 82

Comment: So it definitely does not enter the while loop. I see one change in the first and second query.. tbl_want_job v/s tbl_job.. is this expected?